# How to implement PrimeNG with angular2-seed

Tags: angular, npm, primeng

I've tried to setup an angular2-seed project which works now but now I want to add PrimeNG to my environment but I got stuck with it.

off course my first step: was installing primeng and primeui

```
npm install primeng --save
npm install primeui --save
```

Then I added a mapping @ https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/blob/master/tools/config/seed.config.ts#L129

My component looks like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {PieChart} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
    selector: 'sd-stats',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './stats.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./stats.component.css'],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, PieChart]
})

export class StatsComponent {

    data: any[];

    constructor() {
        this.data = [{
            value: 300,
            color: '#F7464A',
            highlight: '#FF5A5E',
            label: 'Red'
        },
            {
            value: 50,
            color: '#46BFBD',
            highlight: '#5AD3D1',
            label: 'Green'
        },
        {
            value: 100,
            color: '#FDB45C',
            highlight: '#FFC870',
            label: 'Yellow'
        }];
    }
}
```

html file

```
<p-pieChart [value]="data" width="300" height="300"></p-pieChart>
```

This all wasn't enough:
I think I still need to add the following css & js files but I don't know where!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/themes/delta/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.css" />
<script src="node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.js"></script>
```

and I'm not sure if the previous steps where correct as well. At the moment I got the error:

> EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Ah according to this [page](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=44826) Chart.js should also be included as well!

Answer (score 0):

This reply comes a bit late but anyway.

I got almost the same problems as you and after many hours of work i solved it for me. I`ve done all steps to get PrimeNg running like they told us on [PrimeNG](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup) but my application was still not running.

I figured out that my problem was my `System.JS` file.

This is my `System.JS` and i got PrimeNG running with that.
And i placed my `<script>`'s like that:

```
<!-- CSS for PrimeUI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/themes/bluesky/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css" />

<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

<!-- JS for NG-Prime-->
<script src="node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.js"></script>

<script>
    System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        packages: {
             app: {
        format: 'register'
            }
        },
        map: {
            'angular2': 'node_modules/angular2',
            'primeng': 'node_modules/primeng'
        }
    });
    System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>

<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure if that can help you but i hope so.

i can't help you with Chart.js because i never used it.